# Upload a bulk of environment variables on a AWS Amplify app

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-amplify

I frequently have a need to create a new application manually on AWS Amplify via the AWS console, and for every application I use more or less the same environment variables. Is there a way that I can upload a json file containing the environment variables to the amplify application or something similar?

There is a lot of variables that I use and the manual way of adding them one by one is kinda slow, I am looking for a faster way to add them.